# Facebook-like code generator library/API? (ie OTP)

Tags: php, ios, facebook, generator

Is there any library for OTP generation, something like FB's code generator for PHP and iOS? If there isn't how to I (generally) implement it in an app for iOS? I already know how to code for iOS so I just need the general steps, if there isn't already a library for PHP and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a ready opensource solution like [this](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-otp-ios). It generates one time passwords according to RFC 6238.